# cv2.rectangle join closest bounding box

Tags: python, opencv, bounding-box

I'm trying to isolate medieval manuscripts words in a scanned page.
I'm using cv2 to detect zones ant id gives me quite a satisfying result. I labeled every rectangles with an increment number and I'm worryin about the fact that detected zones are not contiguous :
[Here is a sample result of cv2 bounding box zones on a word](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yu2dg.png)

Here is the code I used:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# This is font for labels
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
# I load a picture of a page, gray and blur it
im = cv2.imread('test.png')
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
image_blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(imgray, (5, 5), 0)
image_blurred = cv2.dilate(image_blurred, None)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(image_blurred,0,255,0,cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
# I try to retrieve contours and hierarchy on the sample
_, contours, hierarchy =    cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
hierarchy = hierarchy[0]
# I read every contours and retrieve the bounding box 
for i,component in enumerate(zip(contours, hierarchy)):
    cnt = component[0]
    currentHierarchy = component[1]
    precision = 0.01
    epsilon = precision*cv2.arcLength(cnt,True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt,epsilon,True)
    # This is the best combination I found to isolate parents container
    # It gives me the best result (even if I'm not sure what I'm doing)
    # hierarchy[2/3] is "having child" / "having parent"
    # I thought  currentHierarchy[3] < 0 should be better
    # but it gives no result
    if currentHierarchy[2] > 0 and currentHierarchy[3] > 0:
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(approx)
        cv2.rectangle(im,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)
        cv2.putText(im,str(i),(x+2,y+2), font, 1,(0,255,0),2,cv2.LINE_AA)

plt.imshow(im)
plt.show()
```

I would like to join closest zones together in order to get a word tokenization of my page. In my sample picture, I would like to join 2835, 2847, 2864, 2878, 2870 and 2868.

How should I do ? I thought I could store in an array every coordinates of every boxes then test (start_x, start_y) and (end_x,end_y) - but it seems crappy to me.

Could you please give a hint ?

Thanks,

Comment: you could try performing a morphological operation after applying the threshold...

Comment: Thank you. I tried to dilate, open and close my threshold. I tried with a kernel = np.ones((2,2),np.uint8) then dilating, opening and closing: it did'nt change anything except by increasing the kernel to (5,5) - everything disappeared. Did not I understand what you meant ?

Comment: can you share the original image?

Comment: Sure, thank you [here](http://ttn.univ-paris13.fr/corpus.png)

Comment: I have shared my approach. But it has to be worked upon to get better results.

Comment: Oh really, thank you. Yes, qe are workin on it: this is the first step of our workflow - we succeeded in letter / pattern recognition on words and we would like to build a full process for one specific author

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I proceeded with my approach to figure out individual words. Though not perfectly accurate have look at this image below:

[image]

Pseudocode:

1. Applied Gaussian blur to the grayscale image.
2. Performed Otsu's threshold.
3. Performed a couple of morphological operations:

   3.1 Erosion to try to remove that thin line in the top-left side of the image.

   3.2 Dilation to join single letters separated due to the previous operation.
4. Found contours above a certain area and marked them

*EDIT*

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX

im = cv2.imread('corpus.png')
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
image_blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(imgray, (9, 9), 0)
cv2.imshow('blur', image_blurred)

image_blurred_d = cv2.dilate(image_blurred, None)
cv2.imshow('dilated_blur', image_blurred_d)

ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(image_blurred_d, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV +     cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_CROSS, (3, 3))
erosion = cv2.erode(thresh, kernel, iterations = 1)
cv2.imshow('erosion', erosion)

kernel1 = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3, 3))
dilation = cv2.dilate(erosion, kernel1, iterations = 1)
cv2.imshow('dilation', dilation)

_, contours, hierarchy =    cv2.findContours(dilation, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
count = 0
for cnt in contours:
    if (cv2.contourArea(cnt) > 100):
        x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
        cv2.rectangle(im, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        count+=1
print('Number of probable words', count)

cv2.imshow('final', im)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Wow That's awsome. I do really thank you for your time and your example. Now I see your pseudo code, I tried to do it by myself:
- ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray,0,255,0,cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU) 
- erosion = cv2.erode(thresh,kernel,iterations = 1)
- dilation = cv2.dilate(erosion,kernel,iterations = 5)
I added a testing on h and w to avoid "Multi lines square":
- if h < 300 and h > 110 and w > 110:
My result is similar to what I see and I would really appreciate to read your code and I woul be honored to send you mine. Do you guess why some "black" letters are not seen ?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks [Jeru Luke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6885902/jeru-luke), we could implement this try on a complete page. The values given were very helpful, overall for kernel adaptation in blurring and eroding operation. [The final result on the Bible Historiale Manuscript page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ek0GK.jpg) is yet very interesting. We can see some "black holes" in the identification due to, for what I understand, dilation; it's a first work-in-progress. We will have to manage large pictures and initial big letters.
Here is the code we use to filter boxes, add labels on boxes and save every fragments in separate files:

```
for i,component in enumerate(zip(contours, hierarchy)):
    cnt = component[0]
    currentHierarchy = component[1]
    if currentHierarchy[2] > 0 and currentHierarchy[3] > 0:
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(approx)
        if h < 300 and h > 110 and w > 110:
            cv2.rectangle(im,(x-5,y-5),(x+w+5,y+h+5),(0,255,0),8)
            cv2.putText(im,str(i),(x+2,y+2), font, 1,(0,255,0),2,cv2.LINE_AA)
            cv2.putText(im,str(cv2.contourArea(cnt)),(x+w-2,y+h-2), font, 1,(0,255,0),2,cv2.LINE_AA)
            cv2.putText(im,str(h)+'/'+str(w),(x+w-2,y+h-2), font, 1,(0,0,255),2,cv2.LINE_AA)
            fragment = im[y:y+h, x:x+w]
            cv2.imwrite("res" + str(i) + ".png", fragment)
```

Comment: The result look promising. Thanks for sharing it. Can you share a complete page of a sample? I shall also give it a try in case I am free. Another question.. what do you intend to do after splitting them to separate files?

Comment: With pleasure, and it would be very nice to give us a hand ! Here is [a 24MO B&W complete page of the manuscript](http://ttn.univ-paris13.fr/pagecomplete.png) . Well, after splitting, i would like to pass them (ordered) to another script we just wrote : i made a training alphabet  and computing a multi cv2.matchTemplate on some split test files I could identify a word, or at least, a word skeleton. This skeleton could be passed to some old french bdd dictionaries we have. Our goal is to guess what word it is and build the corpus again, but in txt format.

Comment: Thanks I will look into it